# How to use Pycharm venv's local library when running from a Cmd line

Tags: python, bash, pycharm, environment-variables

let us consider the following PyCharm project which has its own env
[image]

My goal is to run the test "test_translator_dispatcher_new_format.py" from a bash. How to instruct the cmd to use that venv and its local library?

Comment: Activating the venv is explained in the linked question. Afterwards you should place a `pytest.ini` configuration file [as explained here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/customize.html#pytest-ini) in the root of your project. After activating the venv just run `pytest` at the root folder of your project. The tests inside the `test` folder are indicated to pytest by using the `testpaths = tests` in the `pytest.ini` file.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not....

Comment: What "does not"?

Comment: How to instruct the cmd to use that Pycharm venv and its local library included Python.

Comment: Well, there seem to be several questions here. 1º question "using the library" as you put it has several ways of being done, eg. are you using a "development install" or just executing on the local path (your question is unclear about that)? 2º question, activating the venv is, in fact, explained in the linked post. 3º getting pytest to work with a given project is yet another question. All those questions have been answered both separately and together on other threads (and I think on this thread also.)

Answer (score 1):

1. open command prompt from current (project) directory
2. Then activate the virtual environment using this command:

> venv\Scripts\activate

3. then change directory using this command, in your case directory name is **tests**:

> cd <directory_name>

4. Run python file using this command:

> python test_translator_dispatcher_new_format.py

Comment: Thank you vrey much. Just a clarification: How would I check that the above is using the local library and not anyother?

Comment: I tried this out and it worked....however, there is a limitation to use the activate.bat file which across platform would not work. For example, waht about linux?

Comment: Mac OS / Linux, use this command.
source venv/bin/activate, where venv is virtual environment name